# GCC: Force a function call after every instruction (for multithreaded testing)?

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, synchronization, context-switch

I'm trying to test a rather threading-sensitive area in my program and was wondering if there's a way to force gcc to insert a call after every instruction it emits so that I can manually yield to a different thread?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: sounds like it would be an interesting project to modify the compiler to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, GCC does not has such an option.

However, you may be able hack together a script that does that job. You can compile your code to assembler using the -S option. Compiler generated assembler is relative easy to parse.

Don't forget to save the flags and all registers inside your debugging code though.

Comment: if it does not you can roll your own wrapper around yield.

Good luck finding your bug...